# What command could I use to enable NTVDM?

Tags: ntvdm

I try to enable windows NTVDM feature to run 16-bit application on my windows 8 virtual machine .
I know how to enable NTVDM by windows control panel . 
But I have no idea how to use command (wmic ? vb script ? ) to enable it in my batch file.
I appreciate your help , thanks .

Answer (score 6):

**Windows 8.1**

To enable the Feature type:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:NTVDM
```

To disable the Feature type:

```
dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:NTVDM
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'd like to say Thank You for answering your own question, this will help many people on Google. Now I would like to offer an alternative answer in case people come across this.

If you would like to do it in PowerShell you need to download this module https://psclientmanager.codeplex.com/

After installing the module you can use this in your Powershell script:

> Import-Module PSClientManager
>
> Add-ClientFeature –Name NTVDM

64-bit client operating systems do not have NTVDM, however there is an open source alternative that may work for your applications: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nxvdm/

Answer (score 2):

For Command Prompt:

To enable NTVDM in Windows 8.1 (32-bit only):
`dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:NTVDM /quiet /norestart`

To disable NTVDM in Windows 8.1 (32-bit only):
`dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:NTVDM /quiet /norestart`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find that windows 8 have dism.exe command line tool to achieve this .

`dism /online /enable-feature:ntvdm`

Answer (score 0):

In windows 8.1 open start screen, type ntvdm to search, and the ntvdm application will come first in the search result, right click it and run as administrator, it will install the ntvdm feature, after installing restart the windows to effect the changes. Thats it.